# Cloning array with JQuery.Extend, but JSON.stringify looks different from original

Tags: jquery, json, clone

I want to clone my array called myArr into _myArr and would expect JSON.stringify to look the same on both arrays. But they don't.

JSON.stringify(myArr) => ["horse"]

JSON.stringify(myArr) => "{\"0\":\"horse\"}"

Thus it seems to be adding the element index for the cloned array when stringified. How can I avoid this?

```
var myArr = [];
myArr.push('horse');

var myArrStr = JSON.stringify(myArr);
alert(myArrStr);

var _myArr = JSON.stringify(jQuery.extend(true, {}, myArr));
var _myArrStr = JSON.stringify(_myArr);
alert(_myArrStr);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dvnb2Lw4/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem becomes clear when looking at the *correct* string output, verbatim. It is `{"0":"horse"}` which represents a JSON Object, whereas the original output represented a JSON Array.

Then the reason can be explained as:

1. A *plain Object* (not an array) is the result of `.extend` and;
2. `JSON.stringify` will *only* emit a JSON Array (ie. `[..]`) for *real Array* objects<sup>1</sup>.

The object returned is the first-to-merge object supplied to `.extend`, as per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). As such, the original code is roughly equivalent to:

```
var obj = {};
jQuery.extend(true, obj, myArr);
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

While supplying a `[]` as the first object to `.extend` would "fix" this (as such results in everything being merged into said *array* object), it is generally not appropriate to use extend on arrays as such.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is covered in [15.12.3 stringify](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3) of ECMAScript 5th ed which comes down to "if the [[Class]] internal property of [the object] is 'Array'", then emit a JSON Object. While implementations *can* define a mechansim to change the [[Class]] internal property the specification does not provide any formal mechanism to do so.